# How can I compute the theoretical total key-space for 521 bit elliptic curve ECDH private keys?

Tags: diffie-hellman

Assume a dumbed down RSA: the private hey is $3 \times 5 = 15$. $3$ and $5$ are the private key and $15$ is the public key. To brute force it, find the two prime factors of $15$ ($3$ and $5$).

Is there a way to demonstrate a "dumbed down" elliptic curve / discrete log problem that I can compute by hand? I get the feeling that it has to do with integer points on a complex curve so how do I know the value of `n` assuming that refers to the number of integers in the set `{1,..,n-1}`?

Or to put another way - is there a smallest key size I can investigate to learn about brute forcing this formula. Performing countless log functions does sound *quite* CPU intensive.

**Simple Curve Example**

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve the region [−3,3] is a very simple curve where you get a nice "coat-hanger" with values of a=-2 and b=2

[image]
Considering that:

> "the private key is a random integer $d$ chosen from $\{1, \dots, n -
> > 1\}$ (where $n$ is the order of the subgroup)."... and also: "The
>   Diffie-Hellman problem for elliptic curves is assumed to be a "hard"
>   problem. It is believed to be as "hard" as the discrete logarithm
>   problem, although no mathematical proofs are available. What we can
>   tell for sure is that it can't be "harder", because solving the
>   logarithm problem is a way of solving the Diffie-Hellman problem."
>   Source: https://andrea.corbellini.name/2015/05/30/elliptic-curve-cryptography-ecdh-and-ecdsa/

Or to put it another way, how can I prove this, or where did these numbers come from:

> Another way is with RSA, which revolves around prime numbers. Most
>   cryptocurrencies — Bitcoin and Ethereum included — use elliptic
>   curves, because a 256-bit elliptic curve private key is just as secure
>   as a 3072-bit RSA private key. Smaller keys are easier to manage and
>   work with.Apr 7, 2018

Or... perhaps `n` not knowable for curves like `Curve25519` for example?

Comment: I don't understand what you ask. The private key is an integer in {1,..,n-1}. So the key space is exactly n, which is known given a curve.

Comment: Although mathematicians study elliptic curves over both real numbers (similar to computer floating-point) and finite sets like modular integers, cryptography uses only the latter, so no floating-point is involved. Although the identity (aka neutral) element is conventionally called the 'point at infinity', this is just an analogy and is not the infinity used for floating-point numbers. For why elliptic curve crypto is secure using a smaller keysize (fewer bits) than RSA or 'classic' DSA DH EG etc., there are at least 10s maybe 100s of Qs already; please do some research.

Comment: oops my bad, yes of course, i'll change out floats for ints now. i'll something about n.